# Posting file to PHP $_FILES from localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage, filereader

It's surprisingly hard to find a definitive answer to this, I'm 95% sure what I'm trying to achieve is impossible, but here goes:

Front:
I have a `multipart/form-data` upload form. A user selects a file, but has to be logged in before he can post the form. The user can log in via Twitter. If he does so after selecting  a file, due to the redirect to/from Twitter, the file input will be empty.

Back:
I have a PHP script using the `$_FILES` array to move the uploaded file to its final destination. (A solution to my problem would be to save the file to a temporary folder before redirecting to Twitter, but I currently can't set that up).

Problem:
I can store the selected file in localStorage using the FileSystem API (at least in modern browsers). But I obviously can't put that back in the input element. Now I'm at a loss: is there any way to get that file from my localStorage into the PHP $_FILES array?

Comment: Can you force the login before the option to upload?

Comment: If you REALLY want to go this route, you'll have to store the file as a data URI in localStorage, then pull it out, and either send the data URI to your server, or convert the data URI to a blob and send that.  However, localStorage space is very limited, and therefore likely not a good solution for your problem at all.  @FlashThunder has the correct answer, IMHO.

Comment: ^^^ also if you REALLY want to do it this way, you could always go ahead and submit the form, upload the file to a temp folder (NOT localstorage) with `move_uploaded_file()`, then after the login save the file to its new location with `rename()`....

Comment: @a-o I can force login first, but that would mean losing some UX benefits (this is a 'sharing' thing, and user is inclined to finish his post if he already selected a photo etc.). The temp folder as I mentioned in my post is currently not an option.

Comment: @ray-nicholus But that would mean I couldn't use $_FILES[...]["tmp_name"], right? Have to use something like base64_decode server side and handle the file differently?

Comment: No, you wouldn't have to handle the file differently at all.

Comment: @RayNicholus I'm definitely going to try that out, if only to rule it out as an option. The capacity will probably be the bottleneck here though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Login to Twitter via ajax. This way you will stay on your current page and the file input will stay filled.

Comment: Hm that's good thinking. Twitter has an 'Authorize app' screen that the user needs to click through but I can probably figure something out. Thanks!